# A movie about a cannibalistic football team

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched this movie last year, and I think it was released much earlier.

- Most of the movie is set in a mountainiously snowy landscape, in the Atacama.
- The airplane of a football (I think) team from Portugal crash-landed here.
- Surprisingly, most of them survived. Later on in the movie, several people die.
- They try several methods of escape. They do not leave the mountain perimeter until towards the end.
- One person suggests building an improvised ham-radio with the FM Radio they already have.
- At one point in the movie, the team realizes that their governments have stopped searching for them.
- Everybody in the group, but one person, is religious and settles to pray ("Hail Mary") every night.
- The ham-radio attempt seems to be a failure.
- They settle on a disgusting plan to escape. They would eat the bodies of their dead teammates, and then WALK all the way across the Atacama into Chilé, I think.
- I do remember that this plan succeeded; two people did get to Chilé and get help.
- The ending credits had "Ave Maria" for background music.
- I remember it was based on a true story.

Comment: Damn, I was thinking American football, and was hoping for a campy horror movie with carnage on the playing field.

Comment: Googling the terms 'movie atacama airplane cannibal' returns this question in the top spot, and, right below it, the correct answer.

Comment: Came here looking for cheap horror, found a documentary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like [**Alive**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106246/) (1993)

> Alive is a 1993 American biographical survival drama film based upon Piers Paul Read's 1974 book *Alive: The Story of the Andes Survivors*, which details the story of a Uruguayan rugby team who were involved in the crash of Uruguayan Air Force Flight 571, which crashed into the Andes mountains on Friday, October 13, 1972.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alive_(1993_film))</sup>